# How to split a file path with path and name seperated

Tags: java, file

How do we split a file path for example

```
String path=file:\C:\Users\id\work\target\test-classes\ean\sample.txt
to
String filePath=file:\C:\Users\id\work\target\test-classes\ean\
String filename=sample.txt
```

The functionality required is to use

```
Paths.get(filePath,filename)
```

Comment: Why not `Paths.get(path);` ?

Comment: Can you use the Apache FilenameUtils common library? https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use **file.getParent()** to get the directory path.

And **file.getName()** to get the file name.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a FileInfo object from your file (add using System.IO)
you can use the FullName property with Replace() to get the path, and the Name property for the name.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.IO;

namespace Generic_Unit_Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class FileAndPathTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void GetFileNameAndPathTest()
        {
            string fullFileName = @"C:\Users\joey\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Repo Docs and Notes\TestFile.txt";
            string filePath = string.Empty;
            string fileName = string.Empty;
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fullFileName);
            filePath = fi.FullName.Replace(fi.Name, string.Empty);
            fileName = fi.Name;
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Path: {0}", filePath));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("File Name: {0}", fileName));
        }
    }
}
```

And the result:

Test Name:  GetFileNameAndPathTest
Test Outcome:   Passed
Result StandardOutput:
Path: C:\Users\joey\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Repo Docs and Notes\
File Name: TestFile.txt

And Bob's your uncle.

Joey